# Can't start Mongodb shell on MacOS Mojave 10.14.2

Tags: mongodb

Installed MongoDB Community Edition version 3.6 (because my work project requires that version). I am for some reason unable to run the MongoDB shell, so when trying to run mongo or mongod from the terminal I just get -bash: mongod: command not found. When checking which Brew services are running with brew services list, mongodb-community@3.6 is listed. The application I'm working on also utilises MongoDB succesfully. My main issue is that I can't access the MongoDB shell.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was that I was supposed to install the shell separately with brew. This was not the case with previous MongoDB versions and it is not mentioned in the official MongoDB documentation.